# A softer synonym for Chaotic?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm a software developer working some instructions for a web form. The client has requested a special input for their users to fill out if their business is "more chaotic" long story short its a scheduling component.

The detail that matters to you and this question is we're trying to communicate to the user to fill this input out if their employees and business are "chaotic" and basically do not have a rigid schedule. My client thinks chaotic is too harsh a word and is looking for something that won't turn off their users.

So TL;DR whats a softer/more professional synonym for chaotic/turbulent/disorganized ?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: What you mean by *chaotic* and *do not have a rigid schedule*. A rigid schedule for doing what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, you are looking for a *euphemism*.

The euphemism I propose you use is **flexible**.  For example:

> Please fill out this alternative form if your company operates with flexible scheduling.

Comment: Flexible scheduling of what?

Comment: @RichardKayser - The OP didn't explain.  We have to use our imagination.

Comment: @aparente001 I didn't want to guess, but I like your answer. Fits just about any answer to my own question .. and helps me understand what the OP is asking. +1

Answer (score 3):

Their business is **[Unstructured](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unstructured)**

> lacking a clearly defined structure or organization:
>   *an unstructured conference; an unstructured school environment*.

Answer (score 1):

If process control systems aren't working properly in a company, and you phone their customer support line to ask what's going on, they certainly won't say things are *chaotic, turbulent* or *disorganized*. They'll probably say...

> *We are experiencing some **disruption***
>
> [**disruption**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disruption) - *an interruption in the usual way that a system, process, or event works*

(So fill out the form if your business is ***disrupted***)

Comment: Houston, we have a problem!

Comment: My impression was that the OP was asking about businesses whose scheduling is permanently chaotic (or flexible or ...). In that case, I wouldn't want to use "disrupted".  In other words, the definition of "disrupted" presupposes that there is a "usual way that a system, process, or event works," and I fear that may not be the case for the businesses the OP has in mind.

Answer (score 1):

How about **Complex**

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complex)

> 2. Difficult to understand for being intricate or involved; complicated: a complex problem.